# 'spreadsheet' error on google spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have sheet with a matrix that contains some data. I've written this script that copies the data on another sheet and sorts it using different parameters, so I can automatically have everything sorted without having to sort it by hand each time. Problem is, the code only works if the data is 174 rows or less. If I try to sort 175 rows I get the 'spreadsheet error'.
How can I work around this? Do I have to get an ordering algorithm in there? Will it even work?

```
function sortsheet3() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    //ss is the spreadsheet
 var s0 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    //s0 is the sheet I was working on
 var c0 = s0.getActiveCell();
   // c0 is the cell I was working on
   // START SORTING
 var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Lista piante');
 var x = s1.getMaxColumns();
 var y = s1.getMaxRows();
 var range = s1.getRange(2, 1, 175, x);

 var s2 = ss.getSheetByName('Potenziale');
 var r2 = s2.getRange(2, 1, 175, x)
 range.copyTo(r2);
 r2.sort({column: 4, ascending: false});

 var s3 = ss.getSheetByName('Famiglia');
 var r3 = s3.getRange(2, 1, 175, x)
 range.copyTo(r3);
 r3.sort({column: 3, ascending: true});

    // END SORTING
 SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(s0); 
   // go back to original active cell
 s0.setActiveCell(c0);
}
```

Comment: By the way, I tried replacing 'x' with the actual number of columns, which is 21. Nothing changed. True, 175x21 is quite a bit of data... for a human. For a script, is should be a matter of milliseconds. Transfer time should probably be longer than the time spent on sorting.

Comment: tested your script with more than 500 row didn't get any trouble (maybe your spreadsheet is broken, try in a new one)

Comment: Add more details like the data structure of the active sheet. Also consider to create a demo spreadsheet share for view access with anyone with the link and add it to the question in order to make easy to try to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn out I was using getMaxRows instead of getLastRow, as didn't get the difference between the two, so I was out of bounds from the actual content of the sheet. Same goes for columns.